# Wordpress Accordion Menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to create an accordion menu in my Wordpress site. I know there are plugins, but I just wanted to learn how to do it without a plugin.But it doesn't seem to be working.

So, this is my page;

http://storyville.jonmarkoff.com/storyvillewp/our-work/branded-commercial/

and my code;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zhFkc

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#menu-main-menu").accordion({
        header: "ul.main-nav-menu li"
    });
});
```

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: SO requires code in the question.

Comment: I linked a Codepen page.

Comment: If the little bit of JS in your codepen example is all you have, there's no surprise that it's not working. At a minimum you'd have to include jQuery and a carousel plugin for that to work.

Comment: SO requires code IN THE QUESTION.

Comment: I do have jQuery and jQuery UI enqueued.

Comment: Kindly point out where. I'm unfamiliar with CodePen's external resources handling.

Comment: You can see that it if you click on the cogwheel on top of the rightest panel (JS panel)

Answer (score 0):

This should help... [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/26Wqk/)

First: I added an ID to your html div. This will make it unique.  So, here is the updated HTML:

```
<div id="navmenu" class="menu-main-menu-container">
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#navmenu > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
$('#navmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {

    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    $('#navmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }

    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#navmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
 });
});
```

You can then use css to style it to your liking with things like:

```
#navmenu {

}
#navmenu > ul > li:first-child {

}
#navmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
}
```

Comment: Hi @Topher Ellis  I like your code and trying to implement it on a site that I'm building  I have 2 questions though:  1) is it possible to have the sub-menu closed by default
2) is it possible to have a small arrow marker which will indicate on a drop down menu?  Thanks!